# hdf5: where are you? (brew)

Tags: homebrew

On yosemite.  I want to install octave: but hdf5 can not be found.

```
00:48:51/shared $brew tap homebrew/science
Warning: Already tapped!
```

So I went to try to insstall hdf5 directly:

```
wget https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/hdf5.rb
$ mv hdf5.rb /usr/local/Library/Formula
$ 00:47:59/shared $ll /usr/local/Library/Formula/hdf5.rb
-rw-r--r--     1 steve  staff   70014 Jan 13 00:46 hdf5.rb
$ brew install hdf5.rb
Error: No available formula for hdf5
Searching formulae...
hdf5
Searching taps..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been moved to homebrew/science but it seems there is a a conflict with the main homebrew listing for it.

The workaround if you're just trying to install octave is to edit the octave recipe and explicitly point it at homebrew/science/hdf5 for the dependency.

In the command line type

```
brew edit octave
```

Find the line:

```
"depends_on "hdf5" => :recommended"
```

and change it to:

```
"depends_on "homebrew/science/hdf5" => :recommended"
```

Save your changes and brew install octave again

Comment: thx trying that now: in any case  i was not aware of 'brew edit' - that is already helpful so upvoting.

Comment: it is building now - so yes your fix is working. btw "make bootstrap" takes an amazingly long time

Comment: Yeah if I remember correctly octave requires gcc and that takes quite a long time. Hopefully any other errors will be easy to fix using the instructions brew gives you. I just fully re-installed octave from scratch with this fix and it worked ok.

Comment: Turns out there were more steps required: I had a few outdated brew packages.